# cell always returning NULL value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, cell

I have datagridview(dgv) bounded with database but column 5 and 6 are not bounded (for user to enter value in it ) . I want to make sure user will enter any value in these columns . If these are empty , then message to user . For that I am using following code :-

```
            if ((e.ColumnIndex == 5 || e.ColumnIndex == 6) && e.RowIndex != -1)
       {
           var val = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].value;

           if (val != null)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("hello has value");
           }
           else
           {
               MessageBox.Show("NO value");
           }
```

but It returns NULL , always whether the cell has a value or not.

I check it under various events like cellleave , cellendEdit , cellValidating.

No idea , why It returning  null , how to correct it and best approach.

thanks in advance ..

Comment: Have you checked `e.RowIndex` and `e.ColumnIndex` before pass them into `Rows` and `Cells` collection? It can throw an error if one of them would be -1. And could you provide a little bit more code?

Comment: where have you used that line?

Comment: @Dmitry and@MADEELkHALID , I HAVE UPDATED MY QUESTION . PLEASE CHECK ....

Comment: Now update your Caps Lock key to have the status "off"

Comment: ok ...@cody ...

Comment: Try to check your DataSource (e.g. DataTable or smth else) maybe it has been updated before you are trying to get value...Value property must start from upper letter.